# Device's keyboard is above the input

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin application using HybridWebView. Inside of it I have an input at the end of the screen and when I click on it the device's keyboard is above the input, so I cannot see what I am typing. I figured out how to add height on the screen when the input is clicked, but I believe this is not the most appropriate way to do it.

There is a better way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, just put this in the App.cs constructor:

```
Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.Application.SetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this, Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Reference: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=50792

Answer (score 1):

Try thats, I do not remember exactly. If I understand the problem rightly, someone will work for them. Please try and write results.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: I tried "adjustPan", "adjustNothing" and  "AdjustResize", but none worked. I think these commands would only work if my layout were being made native, not in HTML as is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use, in your MainActivity's Activity attributes:

```
WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize
```

or

```
WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan
```

Comment: I think these commands would only work if my layout were being made native, not in HTML as is the case.